# Spring actuator/busrefresh works fine, but trying to use the underlying beans doesn't

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-bus

I've been quite through a lot of hurdles using spring-cloud-bus in this past month, mainly following the docs [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-bus/reference/html/).

I finally managed to make it work, but I would like to be able to trigger the bus refresh directly through `org.springframework.cloud.bus.endpoint.RefreshBusEndpoint#busRefresh()` without having to make a `POST` request. This seems to be doing everything ok up to a certain point.

Where I see it differs from the actuator endpoint call is in `org.springframework.cloud.bus.event.RefreshListener` where the log message "Received remote refresh request." does not get logged.

I'm setting all spring properties as described in the docs above (I'm using kafka).